# Why does this Rcpp code crash when using two push_back?

Tags: rcpp

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test_bug(int N) {

    std::vector<int>    inds;
    std::vector<double> vals;

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        int i_k = k;
        double x_k = k;
        inds.push_back(i_k);
        vals.push_back(x_k);
    }

    return List::create(wrap(inds), wrap(vals));
}

/*** R
for (k in 1:100) {
    test <- test_bug(1000000)
}
*/
```

This crashes. But only when the 2 `push_back()` are used (one seems fine).
It also doesn't crash anymore when I remove the `return` AND change the return type to `void`.

I don't understand what's going on at all; any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

---

Both on:

- Windows 10 with R v4.2.2 and Rcpp v1.0.10
- AlmaLinux 8.8 with R v4.2.3 and Rcpp v1.0.11

Comment: Not here (Ubuntu 23.04, current 'everything').  We need more details.

Comment: Please see my edits with some system info. Also changed the number of iterations to x10.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work here.

##### Your code, with an added conditional `print`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test_bug(int N) {

    std::vector<int>    inds;
    std::vector<double> vals;

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        int i_k = k;
        double x_k = k;
        inds.push_back(i_k);
        vals.push_back(x_k);
    }

    return List::create(wrap(inds), wrap(vals));
}

/*** R
for (k in 1:100) {
    if (k %% 10 == 0) print(k)
    test <- test_bug(1000000)
}
*/
```

##### Output

```
$ Rscript -e 'Rcpp::sourceCpp("question.cpp")'

> for (k in 1:100) {
+     if (k%%10 == 0) 
+         print(k)
+     test <- test_bug(1e+06)
+ }
[1] 10
[1] 20
[1] 30
[1] 40
[1] 50
[1] 60
[1] 70
[1] 80
[1] 90
[1] 100
$
```

When I run from inside R I see

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("question.cpp")

> for (k in 1:100) {
+     if (k %% 10 == 0) print(k)
+     test <- test_bug(1000000)
+ }
[1] 10
[1] 20
[1] 30
[1] 40
[1] 50
malloc(): unsorted double linked list corrupted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

You are really testing two things here: whether you can grow C++ vectors (little doubt there) and whether we can return large vectors.

So another variant would be

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test_bug(int N) {

    Rcpp::IntegerVector inds(N);
    Rcpp::NumericVector vals(N);

    return List::create(inds, vals);
}

/*** R
for (k in 1:100) {
    if (k %% 10 == 0) print(k)
    test <- test_bug(1000000)
}
*/
```

and that works fine for me.

So maybe there is a bug / race condition in the wrapper?